# Combine Stack, Drawer and Tab navigator in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I've currently built, this navigation system but I feel like i've got it a bit wrong as in the order of things. I'm slowly developing issues such as not being able to hide the drawer navigator on certain screens of the tav navigator and etc..

Would someone be able to help me organise the navigation so that it makes a bit more sense?

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

 const SwipeTabNavigator = () => {
 return (
     <Tab.Navigator
     sceneContainerStyle={{
       backgroundColor: theme['primaryColor'],
    }}
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      display: 'none',
      backgroundColor: '#08457e',
    },
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Component1" component={Component1} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Component2" component={Component2} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Component3" component={Component3} />
</Tab.Navigator>
);
};

 const MainStackNavigator = () => {
 return (
   <Stack.Navigator
     screenOptions={{
      cardStyle: {backgroundColor: theme['primaryColor']},
      header: () => <MenuComponent />,
     }}>
       <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="SwipeTabNavigator" component={SwipeTabNavigator} />
       <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
     </Stack.Navigator>
    );
   };

   const App = () => {
   return (
<Root>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{swipeEnabled: false}}
      drawerContent={(props) => <SidebarComponent {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Login">
      <Drawer.Screen name="List" component={MainStackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</Root>
  );
};

export default App;
```

After user logs in the navigation navigates to "SwipeTabNavigator", and I would like the drawer to be available at each screen :/

Any refactor help would be a blessing, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to remove the drawer only for the login? if so you will have to take the login screen out of the navigator and place it separately

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I need to verify if what i am building is correct, as in what the main navigator should be? the drawer? stack? or the tab?

Comment: Generally drawer is the main navigator, you will have issues if you place it inside like if you place it inside a tab navigator you will see the tabs when you open the drawer

Comment: If i am on one of the screens in the Tab Stack Navigator, I can't disable the menu component that lives in the drawer stack, do i need to emit the message back to the drawer or what needs to be done?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan How would you structure the navigator? what would you suggest? can you post some examples in code?

Comment: disabling items on the drawer is not possible as of now, you can refer the sample i made for demo purposes https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/rnn-v5

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I mean on one of the tab stack screens I need to disable the drawer "MenuComponent" on a onClick event :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223565/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-clockingclock).